# What is this? Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to run this query and it comes back with the error: base = {"Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator."}
I don't understand the message. The statement indeed does use th Contains operator. What am I doing wrong?

```
    DataClassOnSiteV3DataContext OnSiteV3 = new DataClassOnSiteV3DataContext();

        var eventTable = (from s in OnSiteV3.SQLPendingEvents
                          from r in OnSiteV3.RepairCodes.Where(o => s.EventType == o.KeyRepairCode).DefaultIfEmpty()
                          from a in OnSiteV3.RepairCodes.Where(o => o.Type == r.KeyRepairCode).DefaultIfEmpty()
                          select new { SQLPendingEvent = s, RepairCode = r, Answers = a });

        eventTable = eventTable.Where(r => r.SQLPendingEvent.EventCode == _eventCode && r.SQLPendingEvent.EventDateTime > _EventDateTime);
        if (CheckBox1.Checked)
        {
            string someCommaSeparatedStrings = "Fail,fail,Failed,failed";
            var stringsToCheck = someCommaSeparatedStrings.ToLower().Split(',').ToList();

            var newTable = eventTable.Where(r => stringsToCheck.Any(stringToCheck =>
            r.RepairCode.Description.Contains(stringToCheck))); *** ERROR OCCURS HERE

            eventTable = newTable;
        }
```

Comment: The *local sequence* referred to in the error message is probably `stringsToCheck` (and anything retrieved from it), which is passed to `eventTable.Where` (from which an SQL statement needs to be generated).

Comment: This worked: eventTable = eventTable.Where(o => o.SQLPendingEvent.EventText.ToLower().Contains("fail"));

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Contains()` operator is not sufficient. What the error message is telling you is that *only* the `Contains()` operator can be used with a local sequence like `stringsToCheck`.

Here, you are passing the local sequence to the `Where()` operator. That's not valid. It's not valid without the `Contains()` operator, and adding the `Contains()` operator doesn't help make it valid. It would have to *only* use the `Contains()` operator.

Depending on what the text actually contains, it's possible you could rewrite the clause like this:

```
var newTable = eventTable.Where(r => r.RepairCode.Description
    .IndexOf("fail", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```

That would work only if you know that the `Description` property will only contain the word "fail" when that word is in fact only either "fail" or "failed" (not counting case). If the text could also contain e.g. "failure", "fails", "failing", etc. then the above isn't logically similar.

Also, I don't recall off the top of my head whether that would be allowed for a queryable `Where()` operator either. You might run into exactly the same issue.

One way that will work is to force the `Where()` operation to be done locally instead of as a SQL query. Which, given the type of filtering you're doing may be required anyway. In that case, casting to `IEnumerable` should work:

```
var newTable = eventTable.AsEnumerable().Where(
    r => stringsToCheck.Any(
        stringToCheck => r.RepairCode.Description.Contains(stringToCheck)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work using the following:

```
    eventTable = eventTable.Where(o => o.SQLPendingEvent.EventText.ToLower().Contains("fail"));
```

This succesfully captures Fail, fail, Failed, failed, Failure or failure.

Answer (score -1):

You need to be checking if the `stringsToCheck` contains the string, not the other way around.

```
var newTable = eventTable.Where(r => stringsToCheck.Contains(r.RepairCode.Description));
```

Comment: That statement is the wrong way round Pharylon. I am looking for r.RepairCode.Description that contain any of the stringsToCheck.